# Site bilíngue com JS

Tags: javascript, html

Precisei colocar um site bilíngue e encontrei esse script abaixo, que por sinal ajudou muito, porém ele sempre mostra as duas versões "BR" "ENG" antes de "esconder" uma delas.
Mesmo alterando a ordem dos eventos ele continua a mostrar as duas línguas.
Estou deixando passar algo, mas não estou percebendo. Alguém tem uma luz?

Este é o código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function createCookie(name, value, days) {
            if (days) {
                var date = new Date();
                date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
            }
            else
                expires = "";
            document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
        }
        function readCookie(name) {
            var nameEQ = name + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0) === ' ')
                    c = c.substring(1, c.length);
                if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0)
                    return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
            }
            return null;
        }
        function language(lang_on, lang_off) {
            createCookie("langue_on", lang_on, 365);
            createCookie("langue_off", lang_off, 365);
            for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName("div").length; i++) {
                if (document.getElementsByTagName("div")[i].lang === lang_on) {
                    document.getElementsByTagName("div")[i].style.display = "block";
                }
                if (document.getElementsByTagName("div")[i].lang === lang_off) {
                    document.getElementsByTagName("div")[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
        function startlanguage() {
            var notdefined;
            var lang_on = readCookie("langue_on");
            var lang_off = readCookie("langue_off");
            if (lang_on === notdefined) {
                lang_on = "pt";
            }
            if (lang_off === notdefined) {
                lang_off = "en";
            }
            language(lang_on, lang_off);
        }
        window.onload = function () {
            startlanguage();
        };
    </script>
```

Chamo a função assim:

```
<div lang="en">ENGLISH!</div>
<div lang="pt">PORTUGA!</div>
```

Comment: Isso acontece porque ele só executa propriamente o código no evento `onload`. Tente remover a chamada `startlanguage` do evento `onload`, mas pode ser que não funcione devido a algum elemento que ainda não foi completamente carregado pelo navegador no momento da execução do código.

Comment: Ao remover "startlanguage" da função, ele deixa de ocultar a língua secundária.

Comment: Vejo que está a utilizar cookies, acredito que a visibilidade da div com a linguagem possa ser setada já no server-side.
Uma outra alternativa é deixar as duas com `display: none`, então tornar uma das duas visiveis no `onload`

Comment: Não resolve, ele toma a mesma ação de quando remove startlanguage.

Comment: Se o script estiver sendo carregado no fim do body ele só será executado depois que o body for carregado, neste caso seria interessante deixar o script no head junto com os estilos. Isso iria forçar o script a ser executado antes que alguma parte do site fosse renderizada. Você pode externalizar script para um arquivo e carrega-lo no head.

Comment: Em ambos os casos o script carrega as duas linguagens. Culpa do coisa ruim.

Answer (score 1):

Criei uma funcao pra você que esta:
http://jsfiddle.net/3ywm7Lyq/

Ao inves de usar cookie usei localStorage, você pode mudar o valor default de linguagem na linha 2 do codigo javascript....

Comment: Coloque um botão para dar um `localStorage.clear()` depois visualizarem o seu código.

Comment: Pq apagar se o motivo do localstorage e justamente pra armazenar a linguagem pra quando voltar no site....

Comment: Simples: Porque é um exemplo, não tem necessidade manter uma informação que não será útil salva no JSFiddle (e sempre que algum usuário acessar o *link* isso será feito). Um exemplo é diferente de uma aplicação real, por isso sugeri que colocasse um botão para limpar essa informação após visualizarem o código.

Comment: A redução do código ficou perfeita @renan, porém ocorre o mesmo do code anterior, ele carrega as duas linguagens, e pelo que entendi no code, se a página mudar (de Home ir para Quem somos) ela retorna para 'pt' certo?

Answer (score 0):

> Site bilíngue com JS?

Só um comentário, O titulo da pergunta foi perfeito mas sua descrição induz as respostas a corrigir o código postado, e não propor a solução mais correta que seria adotar um padrão estabelecido.

Respondendo, acredito que o ideal no seu caso é utilizar o padrão L10n, e existem bibliotecas JavaScript bem estabelecidas que suportam L10n. Por exemplo a [l10n.js](https://github.com/eligrey/l10n.js/) (Que é utilizada para localização do FirefoxOS).

Dessa forma não precisa quebrar a cabeça criando uma nova estrutura pra cada linguagem, somente vai precisar criar um arquivo de propriedades JSON com as chaves das strings e seu respectivo valor em cada linguagem suportada.

Comment: Acho fantástico o pessoal da downvote e não se da ao trabalho de explicar porque. A resposta atende a pergunta.

Comment: +1. O downvote foi, provavelmente, de alguém que não gosta do l10n.js. =)